# Postgres Query - find Difference between beginning and end of week, weekly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column `user_report` with fields

`total_user_count, sent_at`

Which is sent `daily`.

I'm trying to find the `total new users per week`, which is defined as the

`difference in user count from the beginning of the week to the ending of the week.`

I seem to be having trouble formulating this query though, what I have is

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08') as date, total_user_count
FROM user_state_report
WHERE timestamptz_cmp(DATE_TRUNC('week', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08') , DATE_TRUNC('day', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08'))=0
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

Which gives me the total user count per week. But I want the weekly new signups, not the total count

Ideal output:

`Date [monday of the week X], users registered in this week
      14-08-2017                      300
      21-08-2017                      400`

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the lag function.  Something like:

```
SELECT date, total_user_count - COALESCE(LAG(total_user_count) OVER(order by date),0) AS new_users_registered from
(SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08') as date, total_user_count
FROM user_state_report
WHERE timestamptz_cmp(DATE_TRUNC('week', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08') , DATE_TRUNC('day', sent_at AT TIME ZONE '+08'))=0
ORDER BY sent_at) l
```

BTW I changed your ORDER BY TIMESTAMP to ORDER BY sent_at, since I did not undertstand how your one worked!

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Worked like a charm

Comment: My pleasure.  Have a great day